# How to open New Contact Screen Directly?

Tags: ios, swift, cncontact, cncontactviewcontroller

[image]
Can any one please guide me ? Is it possible to open contact screen programmatically in iOS (swift)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this below code. I think I am getting what you are looking for.

```
    let con = CNContact()
    let vc = CNContactViewController(forNewContact: con)
    _ = self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Comment: I think you just upvoted. :P Accept comes in green tick mark.

Comment: Hi @Rishab can you help me for open contact detail page dynamically in swift https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61650767/open-contact-information-details-page-via-phone-number-in-ios-programatically

Answer (score 5):

Its possible to open this screen directly with some pre populated fields. No need of any workarounds.

```
let contact = CNMutableContact()
let homePhone = CNLabeledValue(label: CNLabelHome, value: CNPhoneNumber(stringValue :"number goes here"))
contact.phoneNumbers = [homePhone]
contact.imageData = data // Set image data here
let vc = CNContactViewController(forNewContact: contact)
vc.delegate = self
let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
self.present(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I get the error in `vc.delegate = self ` and the last line where it says `Use of unresolved identifier 'self'`

Answer (score 1):

Till iOS 10.3.1 there is no public api to open contacts screen directly to add new contact. You can use ContactsUI framework to open contacts within your application and then from that contact screen add new Contact.

For reference :-

https://developer.apple.com/reference/contactsui

Comment: Thanks, but is it possible to skip "Add new Contact" did select option and jump to above screen ? same like whatsapp

Comment: You need to manually click on add button over the contacts to open this screen.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to open new contact list but you can open contact list and select add new contact.

Comment: How WhatsApp open contact list for adding new contact from shared contact ?