# Open contact information/details page via phone number in IOS programatically

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, contacts

i want to open contact details page or information that we can open it from 
contact book but i need it to open programatically, i am new to IOS.

I am developing an app in flutter environment, i didn't found anything in flutter for this so i have done this in android via platform specific code, now i need this working for IOS too.

Did anyone know how can i achieve it in Flutter or IOS via platform specific method, Or suggest specific IOS code for this?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: In iOS, you can use Contacts Framework to get contact information. For Flutter, please check this https://flutterawesome.com/contact-app-using-flutter/

Comment: i want to open default contact information / detail page.

Comment: Ok, Using flutter_contact you can open default contacts https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_contact

Comment: thanks for answer dear ... my requirement is to open default detail page directly that plugins are provide their own code for fetching all information